# How to combine interfaces into one using typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

trying to merge responses from both interface , how i would do that using typescript interfaces any help here. thanks

interface.ts

```
export interface  IAdimDetails {
    header: another interface that contains header properties
    detail: another interface that contains detail properties
}

export interface ICustomerDetails {
   header: another interface that contains header properties
    detail: another interface that contains detail properties
}

export interface ICombinedResponses {
    header: any;
    Details: should have both interfaces response here  (IAdimDetails, ICustomerDetails) 
}
```

Comment: You can extend one interface from another.

Comment: Interfaces can extend other interfaces.

Comment: `export interface ICombinedResponses extends IAdimDetails, ICustomerDetails { /*additional members here*/ }`

Comment: @Igor how i would assign extended interface to `Details` ?

Comment: You can do `prop: InterfaceA & InterfaceB`